# Difference between list.First(), list.ElementAt(0) and list[0]?

Tags: c#, list

As per the title... Is there any real difference between list.First(), list.ElementAt(0) and list[0]?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. `.First()` will throw an exception if the source list contains no elements.  [See the Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx).  To avoid this, use `FirstOrDefault()`.
2. `.ElementAt(0)` will throw an exception if the index is greater than or equal to the number of elements in the list.  To avoid this, use `ElementAtOrDefault(0)`.  If you're using LINQ To SQL, this can't be translated to sql, whereas `.First()` can translate to `TOP 1`.
3. The indexer will also throw an exception if the index is greater than or equal to the number of elements in the list.  It does not offer an `OrDefault` option to avoid this, and it cannot be translated to sql for LINQ To SQL.  EDIT:  I forgot to mention the simple obvious that if your object is an IEnumerable, you cannot use an indexer like this.  If your object is an actual List, then you're fine.

Comment: re: point2 - Personally I'd rather have an index out of range exception than a null reference - those xOrDefault() methods are evil!

Comment: @MattDavey It is self explanatory to me that OrDefault methods need a null check. They don't cause null reference exceptions, bad coding does.

Comment: @ProfK I didn't say they caused null reference exceptions. I said I'd rather have an IndexOutOfRangeException than a null reference. It's a personal preference of course but I don't find null references useful in any way.

Answer (score 31):

Maybe an old question, but there is a performance difference.

for the code below:

```
 var lst = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(i);
            }
            int temp;


            Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();

            sw1.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                temp = lst[0];    
            }


            sw1.Stop();




            Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
            sw2.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                temp = lst.First();
            }

            sw2.Stop();

            Stopwatch sw3 = new Stopwatch();
            sw3.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                temp = lst.ElementAt(0);
            }

            sw3.Stop();
```

you'll get the following times (in ticks):

- lst[0]

  sw1.ElapsedTicks

  253
- lst.First()

  sw2.ElapsedTicks

  438
- lst.ElementAt(0)

  sw3.ElapsedTicks

  915

Answer (score 8):

In the "valid" case (i.e., when a list has at least one element), they're the same as pointed out by APShredder. If there are no elements, then `list[0]` and `list.ElementAt(0` will throw an `ArgumentIndexOutOfRangeException`, while `list.First()` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 7):

Another consideration for choosing between these options is that `First()` and `ElementAt(0)` are both compatible with *any* sequence -- any implementation of `IEnumerable`.  (This can be useful as it means you can swap out your variable with a different implementation of `IEnumerable` without having to change any code.)  In contrast, the indexer only works for lists and other structures that directly implement that functionality.

Conversely, using the indexer can be a good way to ensure (at compile-time) that you are getting optimized performance as `ElementAt` has a reasonable chance of being O(n) instead of O(1) whereas indexers are usually presumed to be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no difference at all. They all do the same thing, return the first item in the list.

EDIT: I guess I shouldn't say there's no difference. ElementAt() and First() both have some error handling that they do, checking for nulls and out of range indexes, but it shouldn't really be noticeable.