# linq way to get first name and last name initial in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

i would like to have first name and last name initial through `LINQ.` how can i achieve this.

current implementation.

```
var result = firstName.Value.Trim() + " " + lastName.Value.Substring(0, 1); 

First Name: Milan
Last Name: Patel

result: Milan P
```

I think there should be a better way to do this in `LINQ.`

Which one is faster: current implementation OR LINQ

Comment: Sorry, but how can LINQ help you here? I think you misunderstand what LINQ is. (**simplified**) LINQ is ability to make queries to collection of data, not to single items.

Comment: @The_Smallest: LINQ can also be used on strings, as this is a collection of characters.

Comment: this is one example... i have many cases where i can use the LINQ functionality.. why downVOTE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would use `string.Format` if you need to do formatting like this. Second, instead of `SubString`, you can use `First()`:

```
var firstName = "FirstName";
var lastName = "LastName";
var result = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName.First());
```

Of course you might want to add some validation to be sure exceptions are handled. If you specify `First()` you assume that last name will contain at least one character, so you might want to check that before doing the formatting in order to avoid unhandled exceptions.

Don't worry about performance (you are not executing this code a billion times, are you?); readability is more important here.

Comment: Ooooh, got it) Using all the power of Linq.)))))

Yet you are right, `.First()` - is Linq, and using string.Format - is preffered. You have my upvote.

Comment: @Magnus: conerning lastName[0], see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165462/difference-between-list-first-list-elementat0-and-list0

Comment: in this case, there's not much benefit to string.format, other than maybe readability

Comment: As said, readability is the most important aspect here, so that's why I (personally) like to use string.Format.