# Why is this Linq not working

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, nullreferenceexception

I have a rather ugly object (yeah, I need the Tuple there :) ):

```
var roomToIndex = new Dictionary<RoomNode, Tuple<Int32, Dictionary<GrowDirections, Int32>>>();
```

I initialize this Dictionary like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < roomsAdjacent.Count(); i++) {
    roomToIndex.Add(roomsAdjacent.ElementAt(i), new Tuple<Int32, Dictionary<GrowDirections, Int32>>(i, new Dictionary<GrowDirections, Int32>()));
    roomToIndex.ElementAt(i).Value.Item2.Add(GrowDirections.Top, 0);
    roomToIndex.ElementAt(i).Value.Item2.Add(GrowDirections.Right, 0);
    roomToIndex.ElementAt(i).Value.Item2.Add(GrowDirections.Bottom, 0);
    roomToIndex.ElementAt(i).Value.Item2.Add(GrowDirections.Left, 0);
}
```

Where roomsAdjacent is a List of RoomNodes and GrowDirections a [Flags] Enumerable.
After those initialization steps I increment the Integer values of the 'inner' Dictionaries and at last I want to get the GrowDirection and RoomNode with the biggest value.
I try to do that the following way (now):

```
///Use the Counts to determine optimal FillDirection
var rDC = roomToIndex
    ///Select the RoomNode and the GrowDirection (incl. Count) with the highest Count for each Room
    .Select(r => new { RoomNode = r.Key, Dict = r.Value.Item2.OrderByDescending(dirCount => dirCount.Value).ToList()[0] })
    ///Order those RoomNodes and GrowDirections descending
    ///Take the first Element and used the Dict's Key (GrowthDirection)
    .OrderByDescending(rGI => rGI.Dict.Value).ToList();
var rDC0 = rDC[0];
if (rDC0.Dict.Key == GrowDirections.Top || rDC0.Dict.Key == GrowDirections.Bottom)
    fillDirection = GrowDirections.Top | GrowDirections.Bottom;
else
    fillDirection = GrowDirections.Right | GrowDirections.Left;
foreach (var rTI in roomToIndex.Where(rTI => rTI.Key != rDC0.RoomNode))
    roomCellCount[rTI.Value.Item1] = 0;
```

The rDC has a Type of { RoomNode, Dictionary } and I have no Problem there.
But when I debug and step to the next line:

```
var rDC0 = rDC[0];
```

The debugger skips the line, goes right to the 'if statement' and throws an error, telling me that I got a NullReferenceException??!!
When I look at the values in my 'rDC object' there is no null-Value.

What can it be? Thank you for any tip/help :)

Comment: If your debugger says you are using a null reference, you **are** using a null reference. Look harder. Or post so much code that we can copy and run it ourselves.

Comment: Where should it be?I checked the rDC object, all fields are initialized. Besides I can securely step over the line my rDC is assigned...

Comment: As I said: look harder or post a self-contained, compilable example so we can put it through a debugger as well. Right now, it's just too much work to figure out where you have a null reference. That's work for a debugger, either yours or mine. But I will not do it manually.

Comment: Check rDC's count before the if statement. And check whether anything at index 0 actually exists.

Comment: Is rDC0 the null object, its initialization having been skipped by what the compiler did with the preceding Linq expression somehow? Do you get different results or errors if you change the following lines, and/or put the Linq in a function?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions so far: arao6 The rDC's count is 2 in my current case (which is right!). dbc: Debug build @Dronz: rDC0 seems to be the null object, I get no debug-info about it, the debugger steps over the line of the assignment. I will add the alternative version on the question above.

Comment: You shouldn't use `ElementAt` with a dictionary, there's no guarantee that the item you just added is at any particular index.

Comment: By the sake of curiosity, could you please try var rDC0 = rDC.First() instead ?

Comment: By the way, please replace the other first [0] by a .First() as well.

Comment: Well, I thought I tried that as well, but it seems this would also be working. I just replaced the two '[0]' with '.First()'. Do you know why this is the case? Ty for the info.

Comment: I deleted my answer which is wrong. As Martin said, [0] and First() are somewhat equivalent, the difference is better explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165462/difference-between-list-first-list-elementat0-and-list0

Answer (score 1):

Examining your code the type of `rDC` is `List<KeyValuePair<RoomNode, something very complicated>`. The important thing is not *something very complicated* but that `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a value type (`struct`). This means that `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` cannot have elements that are `null`. This means that `rDC0` cannot be `null`. This is basically also what you tell us.

But then, if you get a `NullReferenceException` as you describe, it must be `rDC0.Dict` that is `null`. However, the `Dict` property cannot be `null` because it has very clearly been initialized to a new `Dictionary<GrowDirections, Int32>` by your initialization code.

So the code you have provided in the question should not be able to exhibit the behavior your describe. Either your code is somewhat different or the behavior you get is not exactly as you describe. The debugger problem you mention could be either a result of debugging the release version or symbols being out of sync with the executable code.

I suggest that you try one or more of the following things to fix your problem:

- Rebuild the solution to make sure the debugger shows the correct source code when you debug
- Switch to a debug build to turn off optimizations that will make debugging confusing
- Break your data and code into smaller parts to get rid of the complicated and hard to understand code you have

The last suggestion is what will solve (or has solved) your problem. Let me just give you a few pointers:

Instead of using `Dictionary<GrowDiretions, Int32>` you could perhaps create a type with four properties which hopefully would make it more clear what your code is doing:

```
class GrowCounts {
  public Int32 TopCount { get; set; }
  public Int32 RightCount { get; set; }
  public Int32 BottomCount { get; set; }
  public Int32 LeftCount { get; set; }
  public GrowDirections MaxGrowDirection {
    get { // Return GrowDirections.Top if TopCount has the highest count etc. }
  }
}
```

Instead of using `new Tuple<T1, T2>` use `Tuple.Create` to let the compiler infer the types of the tuple.

Do you really need the `Tuple` where the first element is an index? Some of your code uses for loops with `Count` and `ElementAt` and accessing collections in that way requires an index. However, maybe you could convert these loops into `foreach` loops and in the process you would discover that the index is unneeded. If that was possible you could get rid of the `Tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently (according to what you wrote) it has to do with the the complex Linq statement, which had a side-effect that is somehow leading to the null reference error, which putting it in its own function contained. You might be able to get more clues about what exactly caused that, by seeing what happens if you put a simpler Linq Select statement before the initialization. See Martin's more comprehensive later suggestion about how you could track down what's actually going on here.

Comment: With the code provided `rDC0` cannot be `null` because it is a value type. Suggesting that it is the fault of the compiler (_Linq parsing bug_) does not seem very helpful and I fail to see how the code in the question is able to reproduce a compiler bug. However, your answer did seem to help as high rep users can see in a comment posted as a now deleted question. It was the _put a simpler Linq Select statement before the initialization_ that resolved the problem.