# Getting elements of List by index in C#

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to access List items in C#. I have a list as `List<int[]>`. I have to assign first three elements of List, which are integer arrays, to variables. This is what I do;

```
int[] c1 = lst.ElementAt(0);
int[] c2 = lst.ElementAt(1);
int[] c3 = lst.ElementAt(2);
```

I also tried accessing it by `lst[0], lst[1], lst[2]` instead of `ElementAt()`. But although first three elements of list are different from each other, all variables take the value of first item of list. I checked values with debugging. What am I doing wrong and also another question in my mind is, what is the difference between `lst[0]` and `lst.ElementAt(0)`.

Comment: please post your code how you FILL the list.

Comment: Show the code you are filling your list with values - It could be a reference problem :-)

Comment: The problem is probaly how you fill your list. My guess is that you have the same array of ints at position 1,2 and 3. For your follow up question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165462/difference-between-list-first-list-elementat0-and-list0/6165508

Comment: There is no difference. `ElementAt()` is used for collections like `IEnumerable`, but with list you can simply use `[]`. `List` implements `IEnumerable` so you can use both.

Comment: ElementAt uses [] internally, and is slower. It is meant to be used with IEnumerable more than with concrete types suchs as List.

Comment: Please look through on how to ask a good question, specially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You have not provided us with an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It is a little bit complicated. Because first I read lines from a file, than get the lines starting with a keyword and assign numerical values to them. But I tested it and list is full I can guarantee that.

Comment: Are you sure the arrays are different inside the list? Are you sure you are not using the same array reference over and over again?

Comment: @HakanAliYasdi post an example that actually reproduces the problem. Using `[]` is the standard way of accessing list elements. It isn't broken. The code you posted doesn't explain anything.

Comment: Okay function that fills the list is malfunctioning. It was working just fine before. Something I did must broke it. Sorry for bothering all of you again :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did something wrong. Because default implementation for ElementAt look like:

```
 public static TSource ElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if (list != null) return list[index];
        if (index < 0) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (true) {
                if (!e.MoveNext()) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
                if (index == 0) return e.Current;
                index--;
            }
        }
    }
```

For anything that implement IList it will use the same indexer as you do

Comment: This does not answer the question at all

Comment: @victor that's actually a complete and correct answer. It proves that the two access methods are identical, the problem can't be reproduced and the OP probably omitted the code with the actual problem. You should probably ask the OP to explain the actual problem

Comment: The result is the same, but they are not identical by any means. I missed the comment where the OP said his code was faulty, so this actually answers what is left of his question, rectified