# What's the difference between [] and elementAt in List?

Tags: dart

```
var ints = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var foo = ints.elementAt(1);
var bar = ints[1];
assert(foo == bar);
```

Both `elementAt` and `[]` operator do the same job. Is there any difference between the two and if no, then why there is no `[]` defined in `Iterable` class when we can use `elementAt` on them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between list.First(), list.ElementAt(0) and list\[0\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165462/difference-between-list-first-list-elementat0-and-list0)

Comment: @MayurAgarwal That question is about C#; the reasons there might not necessarily be true for other languages.

Comment: OK, you're right. @jamesdlin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most languages, `[]` is usually expected to be *fast*: it's often O(1) (or sometimes O(log n)) for accessing random elements.  Allowing `[]` to access elements of a linked list would be technically possible, but it usually would be a bad idea since it'd make potential performance problems less obvious.  Most people would not expect `someCollection[99]` to perform 100 iterations.

In contrast, [`elementAt` does not make any such guarantee](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/elementAt.html):

> May iterate through the elements in iteration order, ignoring the first `index` elements and then returning the next. Some iterables may have a more efficient way to find the element.

So any `Iterable` always can provide an `elementAt` implementation, which is not necessarily fast, but only derived classes that can provide efficient implementations should provide `operator []`.  For such classes, `elementAt` and `[]` *should* be the same.

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer, sometimes you made me realise that to be a programmer, you must have knowledge of Computer Science (`O(n)` sort of stuff here). I got a few questions though, like in Dart, which is faster `elementAt` or `[]`, I'll ask follow up questions.

Comment: As I mentioned, if a class has *both* `elementAt` and `[]`, they *should* be the same thing; one should not be any faster than the other.

Comment: If I can get the element by index (using `elementAt`) in an `Iterable` then why there is no operator `[]` property defined in that class, it would be so much easier to use `[]` than `elementAt` on `Iterable`.

Comment: As I'm trying to explain, the point of using a different function (`elementAt` instead of `[]`) is that it's supposed to convey that there might be a performance difference. Using `elementAt` might be an O(n) lookup whereas `[]`, if available, should be O(1) or possibly O(log n).  It'd make sense for a linked list class to derive from `Iterable` and to provide an `elementAt` function; it would be very misleading if it provided `operator []`.

Comment: Put another way: 
Yes, `[]` is much more convenient than using `elementAt`.  The point of a class providing `elementAt` but *not* `[]` is to be intentionally *inconvenient*.  Since indexed lookup in a linked list would be O(n) instead of O(1), it should *discourage* trying to access elements by index.

Comment: Thank you sir, you explain very well even to a non CS person :)